# Romans 1:14 "ἀνοήτοις" or "insipientibus" is this word "thoughtless" or "unwise"?

Tags: word-study, romans

It is supposed that KJV more literal than many other translations of the Bible.

In Romans 1:14, KJV translated the word "ἀνοήτοις" as "unwise" but the literal translation should be "thoughtless".

The Latin Vulgate of this word is "insipientibus" which is literally: "unwise".

Latin Vulgate has high authenticity and reliability.

This means that Latin Vulgate may has translated the word from original Greek manuscripts having the word "ἄσοφοι".

So, is the word "thoughtless" or "unwise", is it "ἀνοήτοις" or "ἄσοφοι"?

May someone consider the question as pedantic but it is about the accuracy.

It is about the infallibility of the Holy Text. We should use the textual criticism. To reach accuracy of 100%.

Romans 1:14 (LV):

> 14. Graecis ac barbaris **sapientibus** et **insipientibus** debitor sum

Romans 1:14 (GNT):

> 14. ῞Ελλησί τε καὶ βαρβάροις, **σοφοῖς** τε καὶ **ἀνοήτοις** ὀφειλέτης εἰμί·

Romans 1:14 (KJV):

> I am debtor both to the Greeks, and to the Barbarians; both to the **wise**, and to the **unwise.**

Many other translations rather than KJV and DRB translated the word as "foolish" but this is inaccurate. The choice should be in-between "thoughtless" and "unwise".

Answer (score 2):

The KJV was translated 400 years ago and was based on relatively weak manuscript sources. Also, claiming that it is more literal is a stretch.

You are trying to force words that can have a range of meanings into a box. Is "thoughtless" really more literal than "mindless"? And do these words actually capture what Paul meant? Decomposing a Greek word into its roots can be helpful, but it can also be wrong. αναγιγνώσκω doesn't mean *know above* or *know again*, it means *read*.

If you really want to examine the texts, I suggest you learn Greek thoroughly. Using Latin translations, or an English translation from a Latin translation, is not going to give you the insight you are seeking.

Best wishes!